# MySql finding median of a column grouped by another, rather than the median for the whole column

Tags: mysql, median, economics

**Context:**

I'm attempting to take a series of market transactions, and determine the amount of money actually moving per item type. This is pretty much my first attempt at MySql, so the query is ugly, but the following nearly works:

```
SELECT types.typename,
       averages.type,
       averages.price,
       movement.sold,
       ( averages.price * movement.sold ) AS value
FROM   (SELECT type,
               Round(Avg(price)) AS price
        FROM   orders
        GROUP  BY type) AS averages
       INNER JOIN (SELECT type,
                          ( startingvolume - currentvolume ) AS sold
                   FROM   (SELECT type,
                                  Sum(volume)        AS currentVolume,
                                  Sum(volumeentered) startingVolume
                           FROM   orders
                           GROUP  BY type) AS movement
                   WHERE  ( startingvolume - currentvolume ) > 10000
                   ORDER  BY sold) AS movement
               ON averages.type = movement.type
       INNER JOIN invtypes AS types
               ON types.typeid = averages.type
ORDER  BY value DESC
LIMIT  10 ;
```

-

```
+------------------------------------+-------+---------+------------+------------------+
| typeName                           | type  | price   | sold       | value            |
+------------------------------------+-------+---------+------------+------------------+
| Dirt                               |    34 | 1904767 | 2670581874 | 5086836224393358 |
| Light Wood                         |  2629 |   42999 |    2756595 |     118530828405 |
| Dark Wood                          | 24509 |   47344 |    1107771 |      52446310224 |
| Stone                              | 21922 |   18386 |    1505884 |      27687183224 |
| Grass                              |   238 |    5643 |    4554470 |      25700874210 |
| Paper                              |  3814 |   25635 |     861006 |      22071888810 |
| Iron                               |  3699 |  320270 |      58833 |      18842444910 |
| Ink                                | 16275 |    8552 |    2200545 |      18819060840 |
| Loam                               |  2679 |    5759 |    2608771 |      15023912189 |
| Copper                             |   672 |  904612 |      14989 |      13559229268 |
+------------------------------------+-------+---------+------------+------------------+
```

The problem with the data above is that the raw market data is unavoidably corrupted by outliers, as you can see below:

```
select type, price from orders where type = 34 order by price desc limit 10;
```

-

```
+------+-----------+
| type | price     |
+------+-----------+
|   34 | 200000000 |
|   34 |     15.99 |
|   34 |     12.06 |
|   34 |        10 |
|   34 |      7.67 |
|   34 |       7.5 |
|   34 |       7.3 |
|   34 |      7.17 |
|   34 |       7.1 |
|   34 |      7.06 |
+------+-----------+
```

**Core problem:**

99% of the market data is clean, but the outliers destroy the average, and MySql doesn't seem to have a median function. I've found several examples of how to find the median of an entire column, but I need the median per-item.

How would I determine a per-item median in stead of a per-item mean, or efficiently clean the data of these outliers prior to running the primary query?

Note: 
I've tried omitting results via std, but prices of items range from $17 to $10B, while deviation remains relatively low, regardless of price range.

Answer (score 0):

I won't touch your original query because it very complex, but one option you could do would be to use a subquery to remove any statistical outliers.  For example, if you wanted to remove any outlier from the `orders` table whose value is more than say two standard deviations away from the mean you could use:

```
SELECT t1.type,
       t1.price
FROM orders t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT type,
           AVG(price) AS AVG,
           STD(price) AS STD
    FROM orders
    GROUP BY type
) t2
    ON t1.type = t2.type
WHERE t1.price < ABS(2*t2.STD - t2.AVG)  -- any value more than 2 standard devations
                                         -- away from the mean is discarded
```

**Demo here:**

## SQLFiddle

Comment: Good idea, but as mentioned in the original post, the deviation to price ratio is extremely inconsistent between cheap and expensive items, causing any multiplier to invalidate all orders of a given price range.

Comment: I don't follow your logic. Then just change the threshold for discarding outliers.  Your data isn't special in any way AFAIK.  Based on the sample data you provided, the outliers are _way_ outside the first standard deviation.